# Creating .class files without using Java

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to create a toy programming language called Mango. I first wanted it to compile down to Java and be compiled and executed as Java. But I found out it was a very slow approach. So I decided to compile it into Java Byte Code and execute it. I have given the mango code and the equivalent java code. Can you help me compile my mango code into equivalent .class file with byte code.

In test.mango

```
println("Hello World!")
```

would equal

```
public class test 
{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println("Hello World!")
   }
}
```

I did use **javap** on test.java to produce the following bytecode

```
Compiled from "test.java" 
public class test extends java.lang.Object{
public test();   
Code:
0: aload_0
1: invokespecial    #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
4:  return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);   
Code:    
0:  getstatic   #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;   
3:  ldc #3; //String Hello World!    
5:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V    
8:  return
}
```

But when I save this as test.class and execute it, I get the following error in command prompt

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value number 1131375984
```

I have only taken two semesters of Java Programming. My professor told me that you can write programming languages on top of JVM using Java Byte Code. So only I wanted to try it out. I have no experience in programming language design. So any help would be really useful. I did go through Java Specification for any clues but I wasn't able to get anything.

Comment: `javac` is the compiler, not `javap`.

Comment: @Jeffrey I do know that Javac is the java compiler. But Javap produces bytecode from java files.

Comment: N.B. `1131375984` are the four bytes `43 6F 6D 70` which are the ASCII (or even UTF-8) encoding of the characters the `javap` output starts with (`Comp`). That's a problem because `javap` does not in fact emit `.class` files, but rather produces a human-readable analysis of a bytecode file.

Comment: @delnan So what javap produces cannot be understood by the javac compiler in its raw form? What should I do to make it understandable by the javac compiler?

Comment: @Adhithya - `javap` doesn't actually "produce bytecodes from java files` but rather extracts some information from a class file and prints it in a human-readable format. See my answer below.

Comment: @Adhithya clearly not... it's a textual representation of the binary data in the class file.

Comment: @Adhithya You appear to confuse compiler and JVM. `javac` never understands anything but **Java** code in its source form. *The JVM* is concerned with bytecode (specifically, executing it). As others have already explained, it expects the sole official representation of bytecode: A compact binary format.

Comment: Thanks everyone for making it clear for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java class files represent bytecode in *binary format* rather than as *ASCII text*. This means the instructions aren't really human-readable in compiled form—the class file is just a bunch of raw data. Try opening a class file that you create with `javac` and check what the output looks like. For more details on the binary format of a class file you can see the relavent Wikipedia article on [Java class files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file).

Rather than directly outputting binary bytecode, maybe you can use [Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) as an intermediate tool in your compiler chain to create your class files.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will definitely look into Soot!

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider using a byte-code library like:

- [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)
- [bcel](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/)
- [janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home)
- [jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/) *(possibly; haven't looked at it in a long time)*

You almost certainly don't want to work at the binary level.

You will need to become very familiar with the [JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html).

I'd strongly recommend looking at other simply JVM languages before getting too far into the weeds; things get fairly complicated, fairly quickly. You don't need Java experience per se to develop JVM languages, but it's non-trivial, and you do need a fair amount of knowledge to get very far.